# Laravel 5.1 Mail::later

Tags: php, email, laravel, queue

I am having trouble setting up my delayed mailing with laravel 5.1

In App\Exceptions\Handler in the render method I want to mail any occuring errors to myself: Like this

```
Mail::send('emails.servererror', ['exception' => $e, 'request' => $request] ,function($message)
{
    ...
});
```

This works perfectly, except that I would like to delay the sending of the email With Mail::later. E.G.

```
Mail::later(5, 'emails.servererror', ['exception' => $e, 'request' => $request] ,function($message)
{
    ...
});
```

The part where I am having trouble is the following:

`This method will automatically take care of pushing a job onto the queue to send the mail message in the background. Of course, you will need to configure your queues before using this feature.`

I have read the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#job-class-structure) several times. I still can't figure out what precisely I should do to make the `Mail::later` work.

Comment: Have you done what the documentation tells you and [set up the Queue](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#introduction)?

Comment: Yes, Currently i am using sync for development. Or can't i Queue with sync ?

Comment: Will be using redis in production.

Comment: The sync queue runs everything stored in the queue after the controller has been run, which unfortunately means it will be run instantly (for development/debugging). Using redis, beanstalkd, or the other options the queue storage handles the delaying of the item being processed so using the sync driver you're not going to see this unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, I Changed the queue to database now for developping puposes. Still i can't see a job being pushed into the database or a mail being send.

Do I need to create a Job myself ?

Comment: This is so strange, I've never had this much trouble with previous versions of laravel for sending delayed emails

Comment: Are you running the queue listener? `php artisan queue:listen`

Comment: Yes, I got it working now. Had a typo in my .env file (stupid me).
Although I am getting this error `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: While I only changed Mail::send( -> Mail::later(5,